# Javascript array of object section if than else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all this is the first time I've ran into this problem with javascript/jquery. Below I have a part of code that I am trying to place an **IF/Than else statement** in order order to decide what type of **class** I need to place into the DIV it creates:

```
Select3.Templates = {
   dropdown: function (options) {
      var extraClass = (options.dropdownCssClass ? ' ' + options.dropdownCssClass : ''),
      searchInput = '';

      if (options.showSearchInput) {
         extraClass += ' has-search-input';

         var placeholder = options.searchInputPlaceholder;
         searchInput = (
            '<div class="select3-search-input-container">' +
            '<input class="select3-search-input"' + (placeholder ? ' placeholder="' + escape placeholder) + '"'
            : '') + '>' +
            '</div>'
         );
      }
      return (
         '<div class="select3-dropdown' + extraClass + '">' + searchInput + '<div class="select3-results-container"></div>' +
         '</div>'
      );
      },
      loading: function () {
         return '<div class="select3-loading">' + Select3.Locale.loading + '</div>';
      },
      loadMore: function () {
         return '<div class="select3-load-more">' + Select3.Locale.loadMore + '</div>';
      },
      multipleSelectInput: (
         '<div class="select3-multiple-input-container">' +
         '<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="select3-multiple-input">' +
         '<span class="select3-multiple-input select3-width-detector"></span><div class="clearfix"></div>' +
         '</div>'
      ),
      [ect...ect..]
```

I'm trying to insert my **if than else statement** into the **multipleSelectInput** area but I am unsure how to go about doing that since it seems to be some type of array (or object array) or something I don't know what it's called :)?

If I place my **if than else statement** above the **if (options.showSearchInput) {** will that work within the **multipleSelectInput** area?

What I need to changed within the **multipleSelectInput** is:

```
'<div class="select3-multiple-input-container">' +
```

to

```
'<div class="select3-multiple-input-containerADMIN">' +
```

depending on the **if statement else** path.

So how can I insert the **if than else** statement where I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining an object literal (Select3.Templates), and multipleSelectInput seems to be a string property.  You can't put statements into an object literal directly, but you can calculate a variable ahead of time and then set the property value to the value of that variable.

Example:

```
var multiSelectClass = "select3-multiple-input-container";
if (something == "admin")
  multiSelectClass += "ADMIN";


Select3.Templates = {
  // stuff
  multipleSelectInput: '<div class="' + multiSelectClass + '"....."
}
```

Comment: Yep that did what I needed it to do! Thanks for the knowledge James!